# Float datatype misinterpretation

Tags: c++

In c++
float x = 131071.333

The bit pattern in 32 bits should be

0 10001111 11111111111111111010101

Which can be read as decimal as
131071.328125
But output is coming 
131071.335938
Which is 
0 10001111 111111111111111110101011

Which is basically 33 bits which is wrong??

Comment: Let me just say that floating point representation of numbers is [not as trivial as you think it is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Comment: Float has the accuracy of 6-7 digits, so anything after .3 is basically noise. .3359 is closer to the original than .328 so probably was chosen for that reason. Why do you think it should be .328?

Comment: `Which is basically 33 bits which is wrong?` how do you create the binary representation that has 33 digits? That last representation is wrong, both `131071.333` and `131071.335938` lead to the same binary representation in 32 bit.

Comment: `131071.333` is not representable as an exact number in `float` (closest exact is `131071.336`)

Comment: Yup, 131071.336 - https://ideone.com/UksI3n

Answer (score 5):

The closest float to `131071.333` is 
`131071.3359375` (error of 0.003) which is `01000111111111111111111110101011` this is more accurate than the float below your value which is `131071.328125` (error of 0.005).

Here is a handy tool for playing with floats https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: The last output the OP has posted (`0 10001111 111111111111111110101011`)  has `33` digits and based one `Which is basically 33 bits which is wrong?` I would guess the OP has an additional problem when creating the binary representation of the given number.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: This answer assumes that you operate on the prevalent float implementation of [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). C++ does not require `float` to be implemented that way, but it is the de-facto standard for PCs and servers.

You are **kind of** right with your observation of 33 bits. There are **implied** 33 bits in the [float32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) bit format, where the *implicit leading bit* of the mantissa is always 1. This implicit leading 1 bit is never stored in memory, after all it is always 1 (I ignore the sub-normal values in this answer). Since the implicit bit is not stored, then the 33 bits (1 sign, 8 exponent, 24 [significand with implicit bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand#Significands_and_the_hidden_bit)) are stored in a 32 bit memory.

So what you have written as

```
0 10001111 111111111111111110101011 (33 bits)
           ^ 
        implicit 1 bit (also known as hidden bit)
```

This is evaluated as 2<sup>0b10001111 - 127</sup> * 0b1.11111111111111110101011 = 2<sup>16</sup> * 1.99998986721038818359375 = 131071.33593750

It is easy to see that all 33 bits are required to represent this value. Fortunately, the above is actually stored without the leading 1 bit of the mantissa, which makes it possible to store it in 32 bits. If you check the storage of float, you will see only 32 bits (without the hidden bit):

```
0 10001111 11111111111111110101011 (32 bits)
          ^ As if the hidden bit is inserted here.
```

This way there is another bit of accuracy that makes it possible to represent `131071.335938` which is closer to `131071.333` than what would be possible with 32 bits without the implicit leading bit (which would have been `131071.328125`).

Alan Birtles' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55780446/4955498) has a reference to [a conversion tool](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) that lets you play with the floating point format.